# How do I pass in or access a value from one intent to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, drawable, android-drawable

How can I access a method or variable from one intent to another?

I want to do something with a drawable from one intent but I dont know how to access it. Creating an object isn't going to work for my case.

Comment: You can send your variable data with the intent used to start the next activity, then receive it from the second activity using `getIntent()` method.

Comment: Search for "Intent Extra", this is a name-value pair you can send with your intent.

Comment: Passing value in intent - `intent.putExtra(key, value)`. Getting the intent and extra - `getIntent().getBundleExtra(key)` or get object specific extra with `getBooleanExtra(key, default)`, `getIntent().getStringExtra(key)` ... etc. Pass the bundle along using - `intent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());`

Comment: Is the drawable in your resources? If so, you can just pass the ID (an `int`) as an `Intent` extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Singleton.
Here is an example

```
    public class MyDrawable 
    {

        //singleton
        private static MyDrawable mydrawable=null;

        Drawable drawable=null;

        //only setDrawable creates objects
        private MyDrawable(){}

        private MyDrawable(Drawable drawable)
        {
            this.drawable = drawable;
        }

       public static Drawable getDrawable()
       {
           if(mydrawable==null)
               return null;
           return mydrawable.drawable;
       }


       public static Drawable setDrawable()
       {
           mydrawable =null;
           mydrawable = new MyDrawable();
           return mydrawable.drawable;
       }


       public static Drawable setDrawable(Drawable drawable)
       {
           mydrawable =null;
           mydrawable = new MyDrawable(drawable);
           return mydrawable.drawable;
       }

    }
```

1. Set your drawable

   ```
      MyDrawable.setDrawable(yourDrawable);
      //or Drawable d = MyDrawable.setDrawable();
      //d=yourDrawable;
   ```
2. Get it in your other activity

   ```
      yourDrawable = MyDrawable.getDrawable();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Use this technique to pass variables from one Activity to the other.

Comment: Thanks but this unfortunately does not work  for drawables. Do you know any other way?

Comment: Try converting the drawable to a Bitmap and pass it in the bundle. `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();`